# Making Menus In Different Language (Bengali) Using VB6.0

Tags: vb6, internationalization

I want to make menu that can show menu items in a particular language other than English.
There is no font selection criteria in Menu Editor of VB6.0
So how can i do that??

Comment: Have you actually tried some code and failed or is this just a concept question?

Answer (score 2):

VB6 is an ANSI application externally. It is unicode internally and in COM. However anything to do with API calls, directly or indirectly, uses ANSI.

When you create a window (such as a form) you or VB use CreateWindowsExA if you are an ANSI program and CreateWindowsW if unicode. If you use the ANSI version then everything is ANSI. All strings sent to the Window by Windows are ANSI and Windows assumes you are only going to give it ANSI strings back.

When VB was released most installed Windows couldn't do unicode.

You can call these functions as unicode direct with a byte array of unicode characters instead of strings (you pass the first byte in the array only and windows thinks it's a unicode string).

If you intend doing this you'll need to read basic C samples (it's not difficult), as that the language this stuff is done in. Everyone else uses a forms package.

Now for east asian languages, they use DBCS. It's like UTF8 but unrelated to unicode. Windows does conversions automatically.

See non unicode settings in Regional Settings.

This is from Help

When you use a font designed only for SBCS characters, DBCS characters may not be displayed correctly in the DBCS version of Windows. You need to change the Font object's Name property when developing a DBCS-enabled application with the English version of Visual Basic or any other SBCS-language version. The Name property determines the font used to display text in a control, in a run-time drawing, or during a print operation. The default setting for this property is MS Sans Serif in the English version of Visual Basic. To display text correctly in a DBCS environment, you have to change the setting to an appropriate font for the DBCS environment where your application will run. You may also need to change the font size by changing the Size property of the Font object. Usually, the text in your application will be displayed best in a 9-point font on most East Asian platforms, whereas an 8-point font is typical on European platforms.

These considerations apply to printing DBCS characters with your application as well.

Answer (score 1):

The font used depends on the version of Windows, and should be able to handle any language Windows is configured for.

Answer (score 1):

VB6 forms and controls use the current [Windows code page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page) on the PC. You don't mention whether the current Windows code page supports the language you want to use (Bangla)

- If the current code page **does** support the language you want to use, there's no problem. Everything should just work. It's possible you might need to change the font for the form (select the form itself in the designer and use the properties box)
- If the current code page **does not** support the language you want to use, you can't succeed without huge effort. I hate to say this, but I would recommend using VB.net instead if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish what you want by using a resource file. [Have a look here](http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usevb6/a/ResVB6_2.htm) to get you started.

I did this some time ago using Arabic- I used a resource offset (1000 for English and 2000 for Arabic for example). You can then load which ever string you require for example:

```
LoadResString(1+1000) ' to load the English String
LoadResString(1+2000) ' to load the Arabic (or Bangla) String
```

You just need to make sure that when you create your resource file your machine is using the correct locale - hope that gets you started down the right track

Comment: Resource files already have locale selection built into them. Just use the same ID for the same string in the appropriatly identified string table.